# Format long numbers as with K and to 2 signficant figures

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the follwing numbers which I want to format to a more concise length to show on a legend

```
1000000
1200
321
2
0.31243
0.011231132
```

As the following

```
100K
1.2K
321
2
0.31
0.01
```

Ive tried to fix this by using the builtin d3 format function

`d3.format(".2s")`

However the output for that is

```
100k
1.2k
321
2
30m
100m
```

I believe the issue is that the `s` identifier relates to SI units, which are in line with what I want unless the number is below 1. How can I format it to how I am expecting

As I am using `tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));` I need the format function to be in the same format the tickFormat is expecting

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to avoid SI prefixes for submultiples. If that's correct, just checking if the value is bigger than 1 for applying the format is enough:

```js
[1000000, 1200, 321, 2, 0.31243, 0.011231132].forEach(d => {
  d > 1 ? console.log(d3.format(".2s")(d)) : console.log(d3.format(".2")(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I dont know how to pass multiple format specifiers to the function tickFormat([format]) This is the docs for it https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_tickFormat

Comment: Just put the callback of `forEach` you see in my answer, as it is.